# Check tuple to see if there are different values assigned for same element in lists

Tags: haskell

New to Haskell and trying to solve a problem.

I am making a function `conflicts` with the signature `conflicts :: Tuples -> Bool` where Tuples is `type Tuples = [(Char,Int)]`. Purpose of this function is to check whether or not the same character has been assigned a different integer and return false if same characters are given different conflicting values - e.g `conflicts [('d', 2), ('f', 1)]` would return `True`, as f and d are separate characters assigned different values. However, `conflicts [('f', 2), ('f', 1)]` would return `False`, as 'f' has been assigned to 2 and 1. Also, `conflicts [('f', 2), ('f', 2)]` would return True, as f is assigned the value 2 on both occasions - so there is no conflict in the values. `conflicts [('f', 2), ('f', 2), ('c', 6), ('d', 4)]` would return `False` and so on.

So far, I've tried the below, but it doesn't always the produce the expected output. I think it only checks if at least one pair of lists have the same character and integer - if this is the case, it returns `True`. However, this isn't the output I'm looking for; I also want to check the conditions where the character is the same, but they have different integers (therefore should return False).

```
conflicts:: Tuples -> Bool; conflicts = \case { [] -> True; x:xs -> any (== x) xs}
```

If anyone can help solve this, I'd appreciate it greatly. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, conflicts was meant to be lowercase. Have fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution checks whether the tail `xs` of the list contains a tuple equal to the head `x` (i.e. the same character and integer).

You can modify it to find a tuple with the same character, using `lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a,b)] -> Maybe b`. Also, even if there is no conflicts for the first element, you have to continue looking for conflicts in the tail and call your function recursively (imagine a list `[('a',0),('b',1),('b',2)]`).

Finally, the solution looks like this:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
type Tuples = [(Char, Int)]

conflicts :: Tuples -> Bool
conflicts = \case 
  [] -> False                          -- empty list has no conflicts
  (x,c) : tuples -> case lookup x tuples of
    Nothing -> conflicts tuples        -- no `x` in the rest of list, continue checks
    Just d
      | c /= d -> True                 -- found a conflict
      | otherwise -> conflicts tuples  -- the same assignment, continue checks
```

Here I used pattern matching to extract the character `x` and its assignment `c`.